# how can i get images from json file to display I'm already mapping it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image, es6-promise

Right now I'm doing an axios call and getting images from an Amazon source using my api I can seem to make my gallery show even tho I'm mapping it. I  can make text or single images display

```
componentDidMount(){
    let id = this.props.match.params.post_id;
    Axios.get(`APi  + id )
      .then(res => {
        const post = res.data.response;
        this.setState({ post });
        // this.setState({
        //   post: res.data.response
        // })
        const hotels = res.data.response;
        this.setState({ hotels });
        console.log(hotels)

        const addOns = res.data.response.addOns;
        this.setState({ addOns });

        const imglists =res.data.response.pack_gallery;
        this.setState({imglists});
        console.log(imglists)
        <div>
            {this.state.addOns.map(addOns => (
            <Header>{addOns.name}<img src={`https://s3.us-east- 
       2.amazonaws.com/pbx-img/xlarge/${this.state.addOns.type}`}/> 
   </Header>
            )) }
        </div>
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={12} computer={8} >
    <Header as='h1' textAlign='center'> </Header>
    <div>
        <Carousel autoPlay>
              {this.state.imglists.map(imglists => <img src={`https://s3.us- 
      east-2.amazonaws.com/pbx-img/xlarge/${imglists[0]}`}/>)}
        </Carousel>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you need to convert the response to json? What is the output of res.data.response?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.